# Get answers from API request as array

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to make an API request and display them, I think that I have to render them as array but have problems with this. Here is my code

```
      class RecipesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        searchResult: ''
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=ec279fce&app_key=51017bcd32e69bcb0cc8b5f99e8783ca')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => this.setState({searchResult: resp})
      );
    }
    render() {
      return <div>{this.state.searchResult}</div>  //???
    }
  }

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <RecipesList/>;
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: can you show `searchResult` data that you are getting in api response ?

Comment: You can check it here https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=ec279fce&app_key=51017bcd32e69bcb0cc8b5f99e8783ca

Comment: its a object with many arrays, what you want to render in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see your data, just do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=ec279fce&app_key=51017bcd32e69bcb0cc8b5f99e8783ca')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(resp => this.setState({searchResult: JSON.stringify(resp)})
  );
}
```

You can also log your response object like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=ec279fce&app_key=51017bcd32e69bcb0cc8b5f99e8783ca')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.setState({searchResult: JSON.stringify(resp)})
  });
}
```

The problem was: (I saw this error in the log)

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {q, from, to, params, more, count, hits}). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or
>   wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
>   Check the render method of [MyComponent]...

So in fact, the resp in the 2nd callback is an object, which cannot be rendered, so you can either convert it to string to see if your API works, or loop through the object to render it properly based on your need!

Feel free to post here some new errors in your console, so we can find a good way to render your data, thanks